# How to display database records with <details> and <summary>

Tags: sql, html, cfml

I am trying use the HTML5 `<details>` and `<summary>` features to display records from my database. Example:

```
CATEGORY | TITLE
Fruit    | Apple
Cars     | Chevrolet
Actors   | Tom Hanks
....
```

I would like to display the data like this:

**Cars**

- Chevrolet
- Ford
- Vauxhall

**Actors**

- Tom Hanks
- Harrison Ford
- Meryl Streep
- Selina Gomez

How should the query and the display in HTML be constructed? I tried this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY, TITLE 
FROM   TEST 
GROUP BY CATEGORY
```

However, all I got from my works is something like this:

**Actors**

- Tom Hanks

**Actors**

- Harrison Ford

Do I need another query?

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37694190/edit) to include the code you used to produce the results above. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

We use the `cfquery`, `cfoutput` containers to achieve this.

And the group parameter on `cfoutput`

**And this is how it works:**

```
<cfquery name='dataPuller' datasource='whateverYourDataSourceIs'>
  SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY, TITLE 
    FROM TEST 
   GROUP BY CATEGORY
   ORDER BY CATEGORY
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query='dataPuller' group='category'>
<strong>#dataPuller.CATEGORY#</strong>
<br>
<li>
  <cfoutput>
    <ul>#dataPuller.TITLE#</ul>
  </cfoutput>
</li>
</cfoutput>
```

- Note the `group` parameter
- Note the nested `cfoutput`

Hope this helps :)